# Unhandled event loop exception - OutOfMemoryError

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I created a "language" in xtext, which can be generated without errors with "MWE2 Workflow". I also can start a a eclipse new instance and create a file, for the specific language. The first line is no problem either, but when i try to add another line, then this eclipse instance don't repsonse anymore for some seconds/minutes and following error occures:

Prompt:

```
Unhandled event loop exception
Java heap space
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(Lists.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.model.DocumentTokenSource.setTokens(DocumentTokenSource.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.model.DocumentTokenSource.computeDamageRegion(DocumentTokenSource.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.model.DocumentTokenSource.updateStructure(DocumentTokenSource.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.model.XtextDocument.fireDocumentChanged(XtextDocument.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:1191)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:1210)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.DefaultDocumentAdapter.replaceTextRange(DefaultDocumentAdapter.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.modifyContent(StyledText.java:7268)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.sendKeyEvent(StyledText.java:8111)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.doContent(StyledText.java:2481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleKey(StyledText.java:5955)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleKeyDown(StyledText.java:5986)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText$7.handleEvent(StyledText.java:5663)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1108)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1529)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4722)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4610)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5023)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
```

Session Data:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.8.0_31
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide
Command-line arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide -data <path>/../xtext_craass -dev <path>/emf/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse CraAss Runtime/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64
```

There are some (few) similiar "topics", but so far i can see, they seem to be different problems:

- http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/318571/
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=449057

Perhaps i made something wrong in xtext file:

```
grammar org.bs.craass.CraAss

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore 

generate craAss "http://www.bs.org/craass/CraAss"

CraAss:
    functions += CAFunction*
    main = CAMain
    functions += CAFunction*;

CAMain:
    'main'
    commands += CACommand+
    'done';

CAFunction:
    'def' name=FUNCTION_TERMINAL
    params += CAParam*
    'body'
    commands += CACommand+
    'done';

CAParam:
    'param' name=CAVariable;

CACommand:
    CADec | CALoad | CAMov
    | CAAdd | CASub | CAMul | CADiv
    | CARead | CAPrint | CAPrintln
    | CACall;

CACall:
    'call' method=FUNCTION_TERMINAL params+=VAR_TERMINAL*;

CADec:
    'dec' name=CAVariable;

CALoad:
    'load' to=CACaches ',' value=INTEGER;

CAMov:
    'mov' to=CACaches "," from=CACaches;

CAAdd:
    'add' op1=CACaches "," op2=CACaches;

CASub:
    'sub' op1=CACaches "," op2=CACaches;

CAMul:
    'mul' op1=CACaches "," op2=CACaches;

CADiv:
    'div' op1=CACaches "," op2=CACaches;

CARead:
    'read' object=CARegister;

CAPrint:
    'print' object=CARegister;

CAPrintln:
    'println' object=CARegister;

CACaches:
    (CAVariable | CARegister);

CAVariable:
    dec=VAR_TERMINAL;

CARegister:
    dec=REGISTER_TERMINAL;

terminal INTEGER : '-'?('0'..'9')+;
terminal VAR_TERMINAL       : '_' ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*;
terminal REGISTER_TERMINAL  : ('ax' | 'bx' );
terminal FUNCTION_TERMINAL  : (('a'..'z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*'.')?('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*;
```

Hope someone can help me or knows the problem.

Comment: Have you already built the plug in or are you starting it out of eclipse?

Comment: did you try to start your eclipse with -Xmx set to a higher value?

Comment: @Raven: starting it out of eclipse (at time i don't know how to build a complete plugin from it).

Comment: @Dietrich: not yet, it looks strange to me, that it comes to such a problem, when the file only contains 1 line. When possible, i will try it after work today, with -Xmx option.

Comment: i dont know your grammar, what is in your envionment etc => without a profiler one cannot say what consumes that memory

Comment: @Christian: i tried the -Xmx option. With more memory, the time while the window don't response gets longer, so it is no solution for my Problem. I think the language/grammar is to "simple" and the file i created contains only one line with "main". This shouldn't lead to such a problem. When you mean with grammar, the xtext file with the language definition, i posted it too, in my question above. You find it at the end of my post: "Perhaps i made something wrong in xtext file". I personaly think, that i do something "wrong" in the grammar, that leads to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some work, from construct from the error grammar to the working grammar. I found a (possible) trouble maker. I need following line:

```
terminal WS         : (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+;
```

That solves the OutOfMemoryError, but it seems odd to me. That missing this, leads to such errors. After adding this line, the grammar is still no useable, and shows errors that for example '\t' is unexpected. This would be the error i expected, missing this terminal (But not a Exception, and never a Error). When i use hidden(WS), the grammar get usable. Yes, it is copied from org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals. Before i don't come to the point, what hidden(...) is for.

But so far, thx for the help.

Last point would be, if this should be get a bug ticket for xtext.

Comment: yes please file a ticket into eclipse bugzilla https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=TMF&component=Xtext

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're Java is running out of [Heap space](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/05/java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm.html).
The solution for this problem is to increase the Heap size your JVM is started with. For that you need to use the startup parameter -xmx.
This parameter you have to set in your Run-configurations for the eclipse application you're launching.

[image]
Just use a higher value for -xmx which defines the maximum heap space of the started JVM.

Comment: Hello, Christian Dietrich also suggestion with the -xmx option and I tried it today, see (longer) comment above of my post, to see the result.

Comment: do you have a sample file as well? is it just the 'main'. you dont have any (hidden)whitespace nor an anyother rule? is that intended?

Comment: sample file is simple the "main", when i try to go to the next line, it comes to the described error. No at time there is no hidden Elements. Yesterday i shortage the grammar above (in the question post) and add some hidden elements like whitespaces. I will try to add som element after another and ater each adding new element test, if it still works or leads to the problem.